# Why is my Material UI typography not responsive despite theme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I just need my text in material UI to shrink with the viewport, but I can only get it to wrap. I've been following the material UI docs but even their examples did not work in my code.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Grid, Typography } from '@material-ui/core';
import { createMuiTheme, responsiveFontSizes, ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
// import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Search from './Search';
import LanguageFilter from './LanguageFilter';
import RepositoryList from './RepositoryList';
import Sort from './Sort';

let theme = createMuiTheme();
theme = responsiveFontSizes(theme);

const App = () => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState('');
  const [sort, setSort] = useState('default');

  return (
    <Grid
      container
      direction="column"
      alignContent="center"
      alignItems="center"
      spacing="3"
    >
      <Grid item>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Typography variant="h1">GitHub Repo Search</Typography>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Search setResults={setResults} sort={sort} />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <Grid container alignItems="center" justify="center">
          <Sort sort={sort} setSort={setSort} />
          <LanguageFilter setFilter={setFilter} />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <RepositoryList results={results} filter={filter} />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};

export default App;
```

This is the component I am working in. I have tried defining the theme both inside and outside of the component, this is just my last attempt before coming here. Not sure how to make it responsive and can't find anything online that works for me.

Comment: you tried this: https://material-ui.com/customization/typography/#responsive-font-sizes ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I needed to have my ThemeProvider wrap my entire app, not just where it was needed.